# vba appending two datasets based on a condition?

Tags: vba

I have two tables in my dataset and want to create a third table (result) from the 2 tables: table 1 and table 2.
u can see my tables from below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zmyx.png)

as you can from the image above. the main task is as follows:

1. I need to write a loop that goes through table 1 (col_1)  and table 2 (col_1), and checks if the values are equal. if so, it adds the col_1, col_2, col_3 from table and only col_3 from table 2 into the result table. the code i wrote works for these section
2. if they are not equal, it should append the rows from table one, and table 2 into the result table with our duplication. example can be seen in the above table. this is the challenging part that the code i wrote failed badly

here is the code i wrote:

```
   r = r + 1
    For i = 2 To EndRowSummary
        If Not IsEmpty(shD3.Range("F" & i).Value) Then
            If shD3.Range("A" & i).Value = shD3.Range("E" & i).Value Then
                shD3.Range("A" & i, "B" & i).Copy shReport.Range("A" & r, "B" & r).Offset(1, 0)
                shD3.Range("C" & i).Copy shReport.Range("C" & r).Offset(1, 0)
                shD3.Range("G" & i).Copy shReport.Range("D" & r).Offset(1, 0)
                MsgBox r
            ElseIf shD3.Range("A" & i).Value < shD3.Range("E" & i).Value Then
'                shReport.Range("A" & r).Value = r
'                shD3.Range("A" & i, "B" & i).Copy shReport.Range("A" & r, "B" & r).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
            r = r + 1
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: This would take seconds to do using Get & Transform(power query), if you're open to that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. if you are ok to refer me same links and resources, i would read about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get&Transform solution:
In office 2016+, use the toolbar. data->new query->combine queries-> append.

If your tables aren't showing in the list, first use the same get & transform section of the data tab to load data from excel tables into your data model only (not to a worksheet).

You'll need to refresh the query if it gets stale using right-click->refresh on the table, but that's possible to automate with vba.